# C#: State of a Checkbox in MS Excel

Tags: c#, excel, checkbox, interop, shapes

I am trying to acquire state of a checkbox existing in an XLS document via C#. Let me back up here. This is what I have:

- MS Office 2007 + Dev Tools and VC# 2010 Express
- Referenced MS Excel 12.0 Object Library
- An XLS document

I successfully retrieve the Excel.Shape object. However, I am stuck when trying to determine whether it is checked or not. So far I have acquired its AutoShapeType, which says msoShapeMixed.

Can someone point me to the right direction? Thanks!

```
  class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
      Application excel = new Application();
      Workbook wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(
        "document.xls",
        Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value,
        Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value,
        Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value,
        Missing.Value, Missing.Value
      );
      Worksheet ws = wb.Worksheets[3];
      Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Shape sh = ws.Shapes.Item("checkbox1");
      Console.WriteLine("[" + (sh.AutoShapeType.ToString()) + "]"); // msoShapeMixed
      Console.ReadLine();
    }
  }
```

Comment: Well, since the item can be gotten as a picture, using Copy() or CopyPicture() it is possible to analyze the picture itself and find out the status that way. That approach, however, sounds rather desperate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved this problem with help of VB and build class lib. This lib used in C#.

VB:

```
Option Strict Off
Imports Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

Public Class CheckboxReader
    Dim xlApp As Excel.Application = Nothing
    Dim xlWorkBooks As Excel.Workbooks = Nothing
    Dim xlWorkBook As Excel.Workbook = Nothing
    Dim xlWorkSheet As Excel.Worksheet = Nothing

    Public Sub New(ByVal excelFilename As String, ByVal worksheetName As String)
        xlApp = New Excel.Application
        xlApp.DisplayAlerts = False
        xlWorkBooks = xlApp.Workbooks
        xlWorkBook = xlWorkBooks.Open(excelFilename)
        For Each worksheet As Excel.Worksheet In xlWorkBook.Worksheets
            If worksheet.Name = worksheetName Then
                xlWorkSheet = worksheet
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    End Sub

    Public Function GetCheckBoxValue(ByVal Name As String) As Boolean
        Dim found As Boolean = False
        Dim result As Boolean = False
        If Not found Then
            result = xlWorkSheet.OLEObjects(Name).Object.Value()
            found = True
        End If
        Return result
    End Function
End Class
```

C#:

```
CheckboxReader chr = new CheckboxReader(excelFilename, worksheetName);
bool typeFabInstall = chr.GetCheckBoxValue("checkboxName");
```

Works great. Good Luck!

Comment: Yeah, it is kind of lame to have to go to VB to get the stuff done. Thank you!

Comment: I have tried implementing your solution and interop behaves same way in VB as it does in C# for me. xlWorkSheet.OLEObjects returns no objects

Comment: If you wont I can share with you compiled dll? If yes, send me your email.