# how to check a checkbox in excel using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, checkbox

i write data to excel file. but there are checkboxes in this excel file. how can i check some of them by code.

```
mySheet1.Cells[2, 6] = 1;
```

`

Comment: (and if not, then you should use EPPlus library, rather than automation of Excel object in a server context)

Comment: i use Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel. but i looked at the link. he tries to read the checkbox. but i want to click it.

Comment: @SajithK the link you provided isn't helpful to be honest, how does it address this case? The accepted answer in that post to be honest, creates a var and never uses it anyways; supposed to be the checkbox I would assume?

Comment: When you say you want to click it - do you want to toggle the state of the checkbox?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C#: State of a Checkbox in MS Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16459450/c-state-of-a-checkbox-in-ms-excel)

Comment: As far as I can see, the checkboxes do not belong to a particular cell - they are positioned with left & top coordinates. You would have to calculate the position of the cell you are interested in & seach all of the checkboxes for the one that is located within that cell.

Comment: There is information about accessing checkboxes by name here : https://xombe.wordpress.com/2014/08/27/how-to-access-excel-checkbox-value-from-c/  & the checbox interface is documented here  : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel.checkbox?view=excel-pia